# How to match exact “multiple” strings in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to  make a live packet monitoring for SOAP/XML. Here is the code.

```
from scapy.all import *   

def pack_callback(packet):

    if packet["TCP"].payload:  
        payload = str(packet["TCP"].payload)  

        Code = '<ResponseCode>(.*?)<|<ResponseRunTime>(.*?)<'

        pat = re.compile(Code) 
        n = pat.findall(payload)
        if n:
            #print n.groups()
            print n

sniff(filter='tcp and port 186 or port 86',prn=pack_callback,iface='vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter')`
```

But if I use `re.search`, I got `('0', None)`, when I used `re.findall`, I got `[('0', ''), ('', '1763')]`

My question is, how can I get `('0', '1763')` ?
I mean first match `<ResponseCode>(.*?)<` then match `<ResponseRunTime>(.*?)<` not search the XML everytime from the beginning.

The SOAP response is like following:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns3:RetrieveQuotationResponse xmlns>
         <ResponseVersion>5</ResponseVersion>
         <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
         <ResponseMessage>Correct Petition</ResponseMessage>
         <ResponseRunTime>1887</ResponseRunTime>
         <ResponseData>
            <billingDays>2</billingDays>
            <destinationCurrencyValue>0.0</destinationCurrencyValue>
            <dropOffDate>2018-02-23</dropOffDate>
            <dropOffOfficeId>D2</dropOffOfficeId>
            <dropOffOfficeNameParis</dropOffOfficeName>
            <dropOffTime>09:00</dropOffTime>
            <pickUpDate>2018-02-21</pickUpDate>
            <pickUpOfficeId>D2</pickUpOfficeId>
            <pickUpOfficeName>Paris</pickUpOfficeName>
            <pickUpTime>09:00</pickUpTime>
            <quotationNote>There Are 29 Car Types Availables.</quotationNote>
            <quotationOptions>
```

And the speed is almost 110 Pakets per second.
Thats the reason I want keep the wordround as less as i can, otherwise can Python not that fast to process all the pakets.

Thanks.

Comment: why not concatenating the result of `re.findall` together? I don't know exactly what the text you're searching in is, but if it always throws only two tuples max, that should be a fine workaround, doesn't it?

Comment: Hi, Nico, the how list is very big. and the speed is 110 Pakets/s. So I want have the efficiant way to process it.

Comment: Thanks for the extension, this leads to an minimal working example for me!

So there is no chance, that there are mutliple "ResponseCode" or "-RunTime"s in the text given to the callback function? Then I'd suggest to concatenate the findall-Result.

Comment: for efficiency `.*?` should be replaced by `[^<]*` to avoid backtracks

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, attempting to deal with XML using regexes is a futile exercise. While regexes may be able to handle simple tasks, the requirements for XML parsing tend to outgrow regex capabilities, resulting in bugs as well as maintenance & readability problems. It's usually better to start with a proper XML parser from the beginning.

That said, there is a simple way to deal with this particular case. `findall` returns tuples when there are multiple groups, so there should be at most one group in the regex. It could be accomplished with no groups by using [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but simpler is to move the alternation to the tag name, rather than the entirety of the match. For example:

```
<Response(?:Code|RunTime)>([^<]*)<
```